# Setup Elasticsearch for two sites on the same host

Tags: elasticsearch, magento-1.9

I have already a website installed on linux host and Elasticsearch 5.5 too. On this host I have a second website, and I would like to add Elasticsearch on it, but I don't know how.

This is two Magento websites(a Magento 2 and a 1.9), and I use the Wyomind's module for the research.

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I'm a little bit lost betwwen clusters, nodes, indexes... I think I need to create en second node for the other site, but how ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Please give more information. How you import data to Elasticsearch? How you conduct search operations? etc.

Comment: I use the Wyomind's Magento module for the research, and I just need to re-index for import data. My main problem is how to create two separeted instances for websites.

Comment: I don't have any experience with the Magento module but you should use the same Elasticsearch instance with two different indices for two different sites. Check for your module config for "index name" or "index prefix" like settings.

Comment: Yes I have the option, I just added a prefix + re-index products. I think it's work !